# Get raw SQL query from Drupal::entityTypeManager

Tags: 8, database

How can I fetch the raw sql version of the following statement?

```
             $t = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
              ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
              ->loadByProperties(['name' => $s, 'vid' => $v]);
```

Couldn't find anything suitable to try with EntityTypeManager.
TIA.

Comment: @Lambic, I've removed my duplicate vote. Would you mind posting this as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glad this question was re-opened, converting my comment to an answer:

If you write it as an entity query then you can cast it to a string, like this:

```
$t = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->getQuery()
  ->condition('vid', 'test')
  ->condition('name', 'test'); 
var_export((string) $t)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer! I tried and I get different count of results if I use this piece of code. I guess some additional condition is checked in case of loadByProperties.

Comment: Actually, this uses the `__toString()` magic method behind the scenes. You could call it directly: `$query->__toString()`.

Comment: Yes but the whole point of magic methods is not to call them directly